# Why does my Required property not being cascade deleted in Entity Framework Core?

Tags: c#, postgresql, entity-framework-core, npgsql

I have the following class with a required property, and am running into issues deleting dependent properties via cascade delete.

```
public class City
{
     [Key]
     public int Id {get; private set; }

     [Required]
     public ZipCode ZipCode { get; private set; }
}


public class ZipCode
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; private set; }

    [Required]
    public string Zip { get; private set; }
}
```

If I try and load the city to delete it using the following code:

```
City toDelete = db.CitySet.Where(c => c.Id == myCityReference.Id).FirstOrDefault();
db.CitySet.Remove(toDelete);
db.SaveChanges();
```

I get a an `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbUpdateException`, whose inner exception is a `Npgsql.PostgresException: 23503: Update or delete on table "..." violates foreign key constraint.`.

However, if I add an include statement to the above, that is:

```
City toDelete = db.CitySet.Include(c => c.ZipCode)
    .Where(c => c.Id == myCityReference.Id).FirstOrDefault();
```

Then the delete successfully removes both the city and the zip code.  However, according to the EFCore [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/relationships), a Required relationship will be set to `Cascade` delete functionality.  Why is this not happening?  I am using Entity Framework Core v1.1.1 and Npgsql v3.2.2.

Comment: Are you sure `Required` attribute takes effect on navigation property? Can you show the other entity and fluent configuration if any?

Comment: Hi @IvanStoev, that's a good question, I don't know if `Required` takes effect on a navigation property?  The other entity just has a string that is a zip code.  There is no Fluent configuration presently.

Comment: Still it's good to see it. For instance, does it contain inverse \navigation property like `public City City { get; set; }`. Does it use shared PK for FK? Which entity contains the FK in the database? etc. If you post it, I can drop them in my test EF Core context and see what will the migration say.

Comment: @IvanStoev just added it.  Thanks for all your help!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is the generated migration from your model:

```
migrationBuilder.CreateTable(
    name: "ZipCodes",
    columns: table => new
    {
        Id = table.Column<int>(nullable: false)
            .Annotation("SqlServer:ValueGenerationStrategy", SqlServerValueGenerationStrategy.IdentityColumn),
        Zip = table.Column<string>(nullable: false)
    },
    constraints: table =>
    {
        table.PrimaryKey("PK_ZipCodes", x => x.Id);
    });

migrationBuilder.CreateTable(
    name: "Cities",
    columns: table => new
    {
        Id = table.Column<int>(nullable: false)
            .Annotation("SqlServer:ValueGenerationStrategy", SqlServerValueGenerationStrategy.IdentityColumn),
        ZipCodeId = table.Column<int>(nullable: false)
    },
    constraints: table =>
    {
        table.PrimaryKey("PK_Cities", x => x.Id);
        table.ForeignKey(
            name: "FK_Cities_ZipCodes_ZipCodeId",
            column: x => x.ZipCodeId,
            principalTable: "ZipCodes",
            principalColumn: "Id",
            onDelete: ReferentialAction.Cascade);
    });

migrationBuilder.CreateIndex(
    name: "IX_Cities_ZipCodeId",
    table: "Cities",
    column: "ZipCodeId");
```

(it's for Sql Server, but except some specific identity column annotations, it should be the same for other database types)

As you can see, the FK is created with cascade delete turned on. However, the FK column is in `City` table and is referencing the `ZipCode` table. Which means the `ZipCode` is the principal and `City` is the dependent. So deleting a `ZipCode` will cascade delete the `City`, not the vice versa.

Also there is no unique constraint/index on `ZipCodeId` column, which indicates that EF Core assumes `one-to-many` relationship (one `ZipCode` to many `City`).

If you want it to cascade in the opposite direction, then you need to put the FK column in the `ZipCode` table by using the following fluent configuration:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<City>()
    .HasOne(e => e.ZipCode)
    .WithOne()
    .HasForeignKey<ZipCode>("CityId")
    .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Cascade);
```

Now the migration looks like this:

```
migrationBuilder.CreateTable(
    name: "Cities",
    columns: table => new
    {
        Id = table.Column<int>(nullable: false)
            .Annotation("SqlServer:ValueGenerationStrategy", SqlServerValueGenerationStrategy.IdentityColumn)
    },
    constraints: table =>
    {
        table.PrimaryKey("PK_Cities", x => x.Id);
    });

migrationBuilder.CreateTable(
    name: "ZipCodes",
    columns: table => new
    {
        Id = table.Column<int>(nullable: false)
            .Annotation("SqlServer:ValueGenerationStrategy", SqlServerValueGenerationStrategy.IdentityColumn),
        CityId = table.Column<int>(nullable: true),
        Zip = table.Column<string>(nullable: false)
    },
    constraints: table =>
    {
        table.PrimaryKey("PK_ZipCodes", x => x.Id);
        table.ForeignKey(
            name: "FK_ZipCodes_Cities_CityId",
            column: x => x.CityId,
            principalTable: "Cities",
            principalColumn: "Id",
            onDelete: ReferentialAction.Cascade);
    });

migrationBuilder.CreateIndex(
    name: "IX_ZipCodes_CityId",
    table: "ZipCodes",
    column: "CityId",
    unique: true);
```

i.e. the cascade is from `City` to `ZipCode` and the relationship is `one-to-one` (note the unique index).

Now, I'm not sure what is the real intent here. But for sure database cascade delete is directional - from referenced table to referencing table.